# Optimization problem with Lagrangian multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to solve the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}\end{equation} \begin{align} \text{argmax}_{\left\{x_i\right\},\left\{y_j\right\}} & \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log_2\left(1+\alpha_i x_i\right) + \sum_{j=1}^{M} \log_2\left(1+ \beta_j y_j\right) \right) \\[4pt]  \nonumber \text{subject to: }& \sum_{i=1}^N x_i + \sum_{j=1}^M y_j \leq A \\
& \sum_{j=1}^{M} \log_2\left(1+ \beta_j y_j\right) \leq B \end{align}

To this end, I tried to use the Lagrangian multipliers method. I defined the Lagrangian function
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}(x_1,\ldots,x_N,y_1,\ldots,y_M,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) &= \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log_2\left(1+\alpha_i x_i\right) + \sum_{j=1}^{M} \log_2\left(1+ \beta_j y_j\right) \right) \\
    & - \lambda_1 \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i + \sum_{j=1}^M y_j - A\right) \\
    & -\lambda_2 \left(\sum_{j=1}^{M} \log_2\left(1+ \beta_j y_j\right) -B\right)
\end{align}
and I computed the partial derivatives of the Lagrangian function with respect to generic $x_i$ and $y_j$. Setting them to zero led to
\begin{align}
    & \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_i x_i \log(2) + \log(2)} - \lambda_1 = 0, \\
    & \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y_j} = \frac{\beta_j}{\beta_j y_j \log(2) + \log(2)} - \lambda_1 -\lambda_2 \frac{\beta_j}{\beta_j y_j \log(2) + \log(2)} = 0,
\end{align}
which resulted in
\begin{align}
    & x_i = \frac{1}{\log(2) \lambda_1} - \frac{1}{\alpha_i}, \\
    & y_j = \frac{1-\lambda_2}{\log(2) \lambda_1} - \frac{1}{\beta_j}.
\end{align}
I don't know how to proceed from here onwards. Any help?

Comment: Well first I would manipulate the problem so you have _equality_ constraints.

Comment: If you show us your work in computing the partial derivatives, we could help you debug that process.  If you're asking what to do after computing the partial derivatives, that's a further question.

Comment: @BrianBorchers partial derivatives added in the OP. I'm not sure what I should do next

Comment: When you substitute those values of $x$ and $y$ into the Lagrangian, you'll obtain the dual function $g(\lambda)$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I still don't understand how I should proceed after having substituted $x$ and $y$ in the Lagrangian, as the dual function contains sereval sums of logarithms. Would you mind explaining the concept a bit further, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

I will use $\ln$ instead to facilitate the notation issues. First you should transform your inequalities into equations with the introduction of some slack variables $s_1, s_2$ so the Lagrangian reads

\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}(x_1,\ldots,x_N,y_1,\ldots,y_M,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,s_1,s_2) &= \frac 12\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \ln\left(1+\alpha_i x_i\right) + \sum_{j=1}^{M} \ln\left(1+ \beta_j y_j\right) \right) \\
    & - \lambda_1 \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i + \sum_{j=1}^M y_j - A+s_1^2\right) \\
    & -\lambda_2 \left(\sum_{j=1}^{M} \ln\left(1+ \beta_j y_j\right) -B+s_2^2\right)
\end{align}

now, the stationary points are the solutions for

\begin{align}
    & x_i = \frac{1}{2 \lambda_1} - \frac{1}{\alpha_i}, \\
    & y_j = \frac{1-2\lambda_2}{2\lambda_1} - \frac{1}{\beta_j},\\
    & \sum_{i=1}^N x_i + \sum_{j=1}^M y_j - A+s_1^2= 0,\\
    & \sum_{j=1}^{M} \ln\left(1+ \beta_j y_j\right) -B+s_2^2=0,\\
    & \lambda_1s_1 = 0,\\
    & \lambda_2 s_2 = 0,
\end{align}

We can proceed by substituting the values found to $x_i,y_j$ into the restrictions giving

\begin{align}
    &\frac{N}{2 \lambda_1} - \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\alpha_i}+M\frac{1-2\lambda_2}{2\lambda_1}- \sum_{j=1}^M\frac{1}{\beta_j}-A+s_1^2=0,\\
    &\left(\frac{1-2\lambda_2}{2\lambda_1}\right)^M\prod_{j=1}^M\beta_j=2^Me^{B-s_2^2}
\end{align}

Now using $\lambda_is_i=0$ we can (?) calculate $\lambda_i$ and finally to have the stationary points. The solutions obtained with $s_i = 0$ are solutions at the feasible region boundary.

Comment: Thank you. Can we direcly assume that $s_1=s_2 = 0$ if the values of $x_i$ and $y_j$ have to be finite?

Comment: It seems true if $\alpha_i,\ \beta_j$ are non negative.